# ADF Data Flows: invalid column name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to create a simple azure data factory process to read a file (csv) from blob storage and write it to an azure sql database using data flows.

the source dataset has a column with the name "myTime" of type "string".

I added a "derived column" to add a new column with the name "customTime" with the expression "currentTimestamp()"

finally, in the sql sink, I mapped "customTime" to my DateTime field on the database.

[image]

If I preview the data in data flows, everything looks alright, I can see both fields (myTime, customTime). When I debug the pipeline, I get the following exception:

```java
Activity myActivity failed: DF-SYS-01 at Sink 'sqlsink': java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Invalid column name 'myTime'
```

Any idea why the sql sink is linked to "myTime" and not "customTime"? I don't see any reference to "myTime" except that this is part of the input schema.

Thank you very much and best regards
Michael

Comment: Where did you add the "derived column"? Can you give us any screenshots?

Comment: included the screenshot of the data flows

Comment: Can you please paste in your DSL script? It's the code-behind for the UI graph. Go to your data flow UI then click Code > Plan. I'd like to see your mapping. Thanks!

Comment: @MFox I solved this, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the column mapping. You create the new column "`customTime`", but in your table the column name is "myTime".

What I found that is the csv file column name and schema must be same with the Sink table, or it will gives an error when debugging, this my error message:

[image]

> **Solution 1:**: choose the "Recreate table" in **Sink settings**. But this will change your table schema: `myTime` to `customTime`.

[image]

> **Solution 2:** Add the same column name with Sink table in **Derived Column's Settings**.

[image]

I test with the same opreation with and it worked succeeded.

I read a file (csv) from blob storage and write it to my Azure SQL database using data flows. I create a the Sink table with same schema.

This My csv file:

[image]

My data flow:
[image]

**Step 1: Source settings**:
[image]

**Step 2: Derived Column's Settings**
[image]

**Step 3: Sink setting:**
[image]

**Running succeeded:**
[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Leon Yue, thanks a lot for your help, I managed to set up a working sample with the following limitations: 1. source column name (or from derived column name) must match schema of the sink 2. you need to map all columns from the source to the sink (or use the "Select" schema modifier to only select the columns we need in the sink). Therefore it seems there is no value yet to use the "mapping" in the sink as it doesn't work - probably a limitation in the preview version of data flows